# How to move a specific xml tag to a new xml file using python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have multiple xml files similar as the one below:- Name = Updated input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestSuite Name="A123">
 <Group Name="TestRoot" ExecutionPolicy="AnyDeviceAnyOrder">
  <Parameters>
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxA" Value="1" />
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="MaxB" Value="120" />
      <Parameter Type="String" Name="MaxC" Value="master" />
  </Parameters> 
  <Children>
          <Test Name="TestCam" Namespace="TestCase">
              <Parameters>
                    <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxTooth" />
              </Parameters>
          </Test>
  </Children>
  <Group Name="TestMain" ExecutionPolicy="AnyDeviceAnyOrder">
  <Parameters>
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxA" Value="1" />
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="MaxB" Value="120" />
      <Parameter Type="String" Name="MaxC" Value="master" />
  </Parameters> 
      <Group Name="TestMain1" ExecutionPolicy="AnyDeviceAnyOrder">
          <Parameters>
              <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxA" Value="1" />
              <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="MaxB" Value="120" />
              <Parameter Type="String" Name="MaxC" Value="master" />
          </Parameters> 
          <Children>
              <Test Name="TestDriver1" Namespace="TestCase">
                  <Parameters>
                        <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxP" />
                  </Parameters>
              </Test>
          </Children>
      </Group>
  <Children>
          <Test Name="TestDriver" Namespace="TestCase">
              <Parameters>
                    <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxP" />
              </Parameters>
          </Test>
          <Test Name="TestField" Namespace="TestCase">
              <Parameters>
                    <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxP" />
                       <Requirements>
                         <Requirement TypeId = "Abcdef" Source = "User1" >
                         <Requirement TypeId = "ghijk" Source = "User1" >
                       </Requirements>
              </Parameters>
          </Test>
  </Children>      
  </Group>      
 </Group>
 <Models>
     <Model Name= "NewPhone"> 
 </Models>
</TestSuite>
```

I have a python code which is creating a new xml file with some tags only Like below file1_sorted.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestSuite Name="DM123">
  <Group Name="TestRoot" ExecutionPolicy="AnyDeviceAnyOrder">
  <Parameters>
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxA" Value="1" />
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="MaxB" Value="120" />
      <Parameter Type="String" Name="MaxC" Value="master" />
  </Parameters>     
  </Group>
  <Models>
      <Model Name= "NewPhone"> 
  </Models>
</TestSuite>
```

So basically it removes the children tag. Code for that is as below:-

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def removeChild(fn):
    tree = ET.parse(fn + '.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    for grp in root.findall('Group'):
        ch = grp.find('Children')
        grp.remove(ch)
    with open(fn + '_sorted.xml', 'w') as f:
        tree.write(f, encoding='unicode')

path = r"C:\Users\xml_files"

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".xml"):
        fname = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        print(fname)
        removeChild(fname)
```

Now what i am trying to do is move the Test tag inside the children tag but without the duplicate parameters. As you can see in file input.xml there is a Sub Group TestMain which contains the parameter same as Parent Group TestRoot. I want to remove the sub groups and its parameter but not the test tag.

Like this output.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestSuite Name="DM123">
  <Group Name="TestRoot" ExecutionPolicy="AnyDeviceAnyOrder">
  <Parameters>
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxA" Value="1" />
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="MaxB" Value="120" />
      <Parameter Type="String" Name="MaxC" Value="master" />
  </Parameters>
  <Children>
      <Test Name="TestCam" Namespace="TestCase">
              <Parameters>
                    <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxTooth" />
              </Parameters>
      </Test>
      <Test Name="TestDriver" Namespace="TestCase">
              <Parameters>
                    <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxP" />
              </Parameters>
          </Test>
      <Test Name="TestField" Namespace="TestCase">
              <Parameters>
                    <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxP" />
                       <Requirements>
                         <Requirement TypeId = "Abcdef" Source = "User1" >
                         <Requirement TypeId = "ghijk" Source = "User1" >
                       </Requirements>
              </Parameters>
      </Test>
  </Children>     
  </Group>
  <Models>
      <Model Name= "NewPhone"> 
  </Models>
</TestSuite>
```

How can i achieve this desired output.xml? Thanks in advance

Comment: For multi-step XML changes, consider XSLT which you can run with Python's third-party module, `lxml`. See [demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbiE1ap)

Comment: I didn't got that.

Comment: It is free to `pip install`! Alternatively, you can use external [XSLT processors](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) that you may already have on your system: Windows' `System.Xml.Xsl` or Unix's (Mac/Linux) `xsltproc`.

Comment: But how do i use this inside python script?

Comment: Use Python's `subprocess.Popen` to call external programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For extensive XML transformation like combining nodes across different levels, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special purpose language designed to transform XML files. Python's `lxml` (an extended third-party version of `etree`) supports XPath 1.0 and XSLT 1.0.

**XSLT** *(save below as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <xsl:template match="TestSuite/Group">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="Parameters"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="Children"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <xsl:template match="TestSuite/Group/Children">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Group/Children/*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbiE1ap)</kbd>

**Python** *(using third-party `lxml`)*

```py
import os
import lxml.etree as ET

# LOAD XSLT SCRIPT
xsl = ET.parse(r"C:\Path\To\Script.xsl")

# CONFIGURE TRANSFORMER
transformer = ET.XSLT(xsl)

# ITERATIVELY TRANSFORM AND SAVE RESULT
path = r"C:\Users\xml_files"
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".xml"):
        doc = ET.parse(os.path.join(path, filename))
        xsl_result = transformer(doc)

        new_file = os.path.join(path, filename.replace(".xml", "_new.xml"))
        with open(new_file, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(xsl_result)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the detailed answer. One last thing: So i updated input.xml by adding a sub group in  Group tag TestMain which is TestMain1. How can i get that test tag also from that sub group?

Comment: IIUC - follow same approach as *Children* in XSLT with an additional `apply-templates` line to second template and a whole new template for the sub group. Be sure to adjust XPaths in all `select` values. Play around with online demo for testing.